# How to use transaction dependency tags (provides/requires)?

Tags: transactions

I could not find much information/documentation on how to use the `provides`/`requires` tags (`TransactionTag`) Can someone please provide an example?  The tag is a vector of bytes.  Should I assume these are user-defined strings?  Where/how do you specify them when creating a transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK the most common example cited for explaining this where the `requires`/`provides` tag is used to provide nonce information for the current transaction in order to be properly considered a valid tx. The `provides` tag for a tx with nonce `N` would be the `requires` for a tx with nonce `N+1`.

Here's an example which constructs the `provides` and `requires` tag for a the checking correct nonce of a transaction:

```rust
fn validate(
        &self,
        who: &Self::AccountId,
        _call: &Self::Call,
        _info: &DispatchInfoOf<Self::Call>,
        _len: usize,
    ) -> TransactionValidity {
        // check index
        let account = crate::Account::<T>::get(who);
        if self.0 < account.nonce {
            return InvalidTransaction::Stale.into()
        }

        let provides = vec![Encode::encode(&(who, self.0))];
        let requires = if account.nonce < self.0 {
            vec![Encode::encode(&(who, self.0 - One::one()))]
        } else {
            vec![]
        };

        Ok(ValidTransaction {
            priority: 0,
            requires,
            provides,
            longevity: TransactionLongevity::max_value(),
            propagate: true,
        })
    }
```

Comment: What would these tags look like?  Where are the tags set?  Where (file/function) in the Substrate code is the dependency graph built/evaluated?

Comment: Good question, and I don't have an answer for you. But my guess would be to look at where Transactions are built. Check out this doc: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/pallet_prelude/struct.ValidTransaction.html and look for uses of `with_tag_prefix`

Comment: I found one example that shows that they are strings.  e.g.  `ValidTransaction::with_tag_prefix("BabeEquivocation")`

Comment: But it would be great to see a full but simple example.

Comment: I am editing my answer and adding an example.

Comment: Excellent.  Can you explain the use of `self.0`?  Is that a tuple where the _nonce_ value is at index 0?

Comment: Yes, as you can see from the code `pub struct CheckNonce<T: Config>(#[codec(compact)] pub T::Index);`, It's a tuple containing the Nonce, referred to as `Index` here.

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/system/src/extensions/check_nonce.rs#L40